# PostgreSQL RULEs and NEW pseudo relation

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm struggling to implement class-like hierarchy storage on top of PostgreSQL.
Currently I am creating a single table for each class with descendant tables containing `pkey` and fields diff.

Consider a simple case:

[image: primitive class hierarchy]

This hierarchy would be represented as the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE A_c (id uuid CONSTRAINT A_pkey PRIMARY KEY, class_ text, name text);
CREATE TABLE B_c (id uuid CONSTRAINT B_pkey PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES A_c ON DELETE CASCADE, ival integer);
CREATE TABLE C_c (id uuid CONSTRAINT C_pkey PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES A_c ON DELETE CASCADE, dval double precision);
CREATE TABLE D_c (id uuid CONSTRAINT D_pkey PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES C_c ON DELETE CASCADE, min double precision, max double precision);
```

I do want my tables to be in sync and allow me to read and modify data without knowing all the messy details, hence I create custom updatable views.
I do expect some bulk operations on my views so I resort to `RULE` system.

```
CREATE TABLE A (id uuid, name text);
CREATE RULE "_RETURN" AS ON SELECT TO A DO INSTEAD SELECT id, name FROM A_c;
CREATE RULE "_insert_into_A" AS ON INSERT TO A DO INSTEAD INSERT INTO A_c (id, class_, name) VALUES (NEW.id, 'A', NEW.name);

CREATE TABLE B (id uuid, name text, ival integer);
CREATE RULE "_RETURN" AS ON SELECT TO B DO INSTEAD SELECT a.id, a.name, b.ival FROM B_c b, A a WHERE a.id = b.id;
CREATE RULE "_insert_into_B" AS ON INSERT TO B DO INSTEAD (INSERT INTO A_c (id, class_, name) VALUES (NEW.id, 'B', NEW.name); 
                                                       INSERT INTO B_c (id, ival) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.ival));

CREATE TABLE C (id uuid, name text, dval double precision);
CREATE RULE "_RETURN" AS ON SELECT TO C DO INSTEAD SELECT a.id, a.name, c.dval FROM C_c c, A a WHERE a.id = c.id;
CREATE RULE "_insert_into_C" AS ON INSERT TO C DO INSTEAD (INSERT INTO A_c (id, class_, name) VALUES (NEW.id, 'C', NEW.name); 
                                                       INSERT INTO C_c (id, dval) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.dval));

CREATE TABLE D (id uuid, name text, dval double precision, min double precision, max double precision);
CREATE RULE "_RETURN" AS ON SELECT TO D DO INSTEAD SELECT c.id, c.name, c.dval, d.min, d.max FROM D_c d, C c WHERE c.id = d.id;
CREATE RULE "_insert_into_D" AS ON INSERT TO D DO INSTEAD (INSERT INTO A_c (id, class_, name) VALUES (NEW.id, 'D', NEW.name); 
                                                       INSERT INTO C_c (id, dval) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.dval);
                                                       INSERT INTO D_c (id, min, max) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.min, NEW.max));
```

At the first glance everything is fine and dandy.

```
INSERT INTO B (id, name, ival) VALUES ('87a9e442-e1ff-4d92-bf36-756420ad1dfa', 'test', 10);
INSERT INTO C (id, name, dval) VALUES ('407424d9-c709-45e2-a72c-03a9dd6fdc16', 'test2', 3.0);
INSERT INTO D (id, name, dval, min, max) VALUES ('c174594d-e9fe-4e95-b1a3-f8c6a6e83c53', 'test3', 1.0, 0.0, 2.0);

SELECT * FROM D;
              id                  | name  | dval | min | max 
--------------------------------------+-------+------+-----+-----
 c174594d-e9fe-4e95-b1a3-f8c6a6e83c53 | test3 |    1 |   0 |   2
(1 row)

SELECT * FROM C;
              id                  | name  | dval 
--------------------------------------+-------+------
 407424d9-c709-45e2-a72c-03a9dd6fdc16 | test2 |    3
 c174594d-e9fe-4e95-b1a3-f8c6a6e83c53 | test3 |    1
(2 rows)

SELECT * FROM B;
              id                  | name | ival 
--------------------------------------+------+------
 87a9e442-e1ff-4d92-bf36-756420ad1dfa | test |   10
(1 row)

SELECT * FROM A;
              id                  | name  
--------------------------------------+-------
 87a9e442-e1ff-4d92-bf36-756420ad1dfa | test
 407424d9-c709-45e2-a72c-03a9dd6fdc16 | test2
 c174594d-e9fe-4e95-b1a3-f8c6a6e83c53 | test3
(3 rows)
```

At the second glance though, it looks like my insertion rules reevalute `NEW` fields in each insert, which means two things:

1. Any expensive function be called for each level of class hierarchy.
2. Any function with nondetermenistic output evaluates multiple times with different values.

   ```
   INSERT INTO D (id, name, dval, min, max) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), 'test', 1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
   ERROR:  insert or update on table "c_c" violates foreign key constraint "c_c_id_fkey"
   DETAILS:  Key (id)=(ac75a666-adac-4f79-85b6-b802199f5c5f) is not present in table "a_c".
   ```

I've tried reimplementing `INSERT` rules using `WITH`, however it is forbidden to use `NEW` pseudo relation within `WITH`. Another option would be to wrap insertion into an `SQL` function, unfortunately function seems to be an optimization barrier, which means that essentialy I receive more or less `TRIGGER` performance with function being called for each row.

So the question is. Did I miss any other option to make my implementation work with arbitrary data (literals, function calls, etc...) in `INSERT` statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some more investigation. So basically I'm hitting fundamental `RULE` limitation here, which is actualy stated in the documentation since `9.5` version:

> Caution
>
> In many cases, tasks that could be performed by rules on INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE are better done with triggers. Triggers are notationally a bit more complicated, but their semantics are much simpler to understand. Rules tend to have surprising results when the original query contains volatile functions: volatile functions may get executed more times than expected in the process of carrying out the rules.
>
> Also, there are some cases that are not supported by these types of rules at all, notably including WITH clauses in the original query and multiple-assignment sub-SELECTs in the SET list of UPDATE queries. This is because copying these constructs into a rule query would result in multiple evaluations of the sub-query, contrary to the express intent of the query's author.

The point is while `_RETURN` rule allows only a single query tree, all the other rules `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` allow splitting a single query tree into a multitude of query trees. However this happens entirely as a query rewrite procedure so any `CTE` or any function call will be duplicated for each new query tree.

Overall the only way to go with the suggested implementation is `TRIGGER` implementation of all the data modification routines.

The alternate option would be to create a full fields table for each class without any `FK` relation between them, which will make `INSERT` a single table operation, `SELECT` will be a `UNION ALL` aggregation of the class table and all of its descendant classes tables and `DELETE/UPDATE` will produce a query tree for the class table and each of its descendant class tables. Huge class hierarchies (hundreds) will cause a significant planner strain for `DELETE/UPDATE` queries perormed someplace near the root of the class tree.